# How do I case Object to Long

Tags: java, casting, long-integer

I have an object which returns the value  24566.999 ( which actually denotes time in miliseconds)
Now I want to convert it to Long
I tried doing this

```
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        Object x = js.executeScript("return Date.now() - performance.timeOrigin;");
        long hh = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(x));
```

This throws a number format exception as String has a "." in it.
Also, I can't ignore it as it actually tells the time and I actually need to divide it by 1000 to get the time in seconds
How can I convert it to long?

**EDIT**
Also, I tried doing this way

```
public Long getPageLoadTime(WebDriver driver) {
Object x = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return Date.now() - performance.timeOrigin;")
         return ((Double) x.longValue();
    }
```

This is how I am calling it outside

```
System.out.println("PageLoad Time: " + (commonUtils.getPageLoadTime(utils.getWebDriver())) / 1000 + " Seconds");
```

It throws This throws java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Comment: Cast it to `double` instead?

Comment: Why not split the string and then covert the part of it before the decimal?

Comment: What `long` value were you expecting 24566.999 to be cast to?

Comment: @Guy I tried doing this
 return ((Double) x.longValue();
This throwing java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Comment: Don't cast it to `long` at all, cast `x` directly to `double`.

Comment: @Guy let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take look at [BigDecimal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bigdecimal-class-java/#:%7E:text=The%20BigDecimal%20class%20provides%20operations,the%20time%20complexity%20a%20bit.) for this kind of scenario. Try the code below:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Object x = js.executeScript("return Date.now() - performance.timeOrigin;");
long hh = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(x)).longValue();
```

Comment: Why not use Long.parseLong instead?

Comment: @m0skit0 Because '.' character is not a number. If you will go deep inside `parseLong` function you will find that `Character.digit(codePoint,radix)` function which returns the numeric value represented by the character in the specified radix. To read more 
 click here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html